# Problem using $or for an update at MongoDB, Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators

Tags: mongodb

I want to make this update at MongoDb using Robot. I need to update a field with two posible values in the search using regex.

I need to put today date to all models Samsung and Iphone.

This is my sentence

```
db.CatalogoAntel.updateMany  ({$or : [{modelo : {$regex: "iphone", $options:"i"}}, 
{modelo : { $regex: "samsung", $options:"i" }}]}, {set: {FecActualizacion: new Date()} })
```

The error I got was

```
Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators :
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:601:1
@(shell):1:1
```

I found this problem only when I try to put more than one value at the search sentence. I revise my code but I can't see what is wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) update operator to add/update values (you're using `set`).

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  $or : [
    {
      modelo : { $regex: "iphone", $options: "i" }
    }, 
    {
      modelo : { $regex: "samsung", $options: "i" }
    }
  ]
}, { $set: { FecActualizacion: new Date() } })
```